# sqlite, accessing a single DB file from multiple processes

Tags: sqlite

I have a setup sending a *message* from *ONE* process to an *OTHER* process, the sending is done by:

1. adding *message* to a **sqlite** database
2. sending the *message* to the next process
3. delete the *message* from the **sqlite** database

For testing I connect 4 *filter* and a final *server* together and the server will just echo the message back… all together there are 2x4+1=9 insert **and** delete in a very short time in 4+1=5 processes. All 5 processes using the **same** database with a private db handle. To get at least **some** steps done… I *open* and *close* the db-handel for every new **sql** operation. If I don't do this and if I dont use **WAL** transaction format the **sqlite** database fails always after 2 steps.

to make it short **sqlite** fails every time… **sqlite** works for a couple of steps but endup final in an infinite **SQLITE_BUSY**. I try a lot of different configurations… my *latest* pragmas are:

```
EXEC(4,"PRAGMA synchronous  = NORMAL    ;")
EXEC(5,"PRAGMA journal_mode = WAL       ;")
EXEC(6,"PRAGMA locking_mode = NORMAL    ;")
```

a typical output is:

1. *ft0-3* are the **filter**
2. *sv0* is the **server**
3. *transLId* is the **sqlite** rowid
4. *db* is the database handle in duty

example…

```
---- service-2-2-(1|binary|uds|c.uds.spawn) start
S> {ft0         :pid(64414):tid(0x7f60eed77780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x24d17e0     ):pSqlInsertReadTrans }: START insert: db<(nil)>
S> {ft0         :pid(64414):tid(0x7f60eed77780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x24d17e0     ):pSqlInsertReadTrans }: DONE  insert: db<0x24e0f98>, transLId<1>
S> {ft1         :pid(64415):tid(0x7f62e168f780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x9fa650      ):pSqlInsertReadTrans }: START insert: db<(nil)>
S> {ft1         :pid(64415):tid(0x7f62e168f780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x9fa650      ):pSqlInsertReadTrans }: DONE  insert: db<0xa096a8>, transLId<2>
S> {ft2         :pid(64416):tid(0x7f4f3fa74780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x100a320     ):pSqlInsertReadTrans }: START insert: db<(nil)>
S> {ft0         :pid(64414):tid(0x7f60eed77780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x24d17e0     ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: START delete: db<0x24e0328>, transLId<1>
S> {ft2         :pid(64416):tid(0x7f4f3fa74780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x100a320     ):pSqlInsertReadTrans }: SQLITE_BUSY:  db<0x1018bc8>
S> {ft0         :pid(64414):tid(0x7f60eed77780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x24d17e0     ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: DONE  delete: db<0x24e0328>, transLId<1>
S> {ft2         :pid(64416):tid(0x7f4f3fa74780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x100a320     ):pSqlInsertReadTrans }: DONE  insert: db<0x1018bc8>, transLId<3>
S> {ft3         :pid(64417):tid(0x7fbf3b3da780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x1fedff0     ):pSqlInsertReadTrans }: START insert: db<(nil)>
S> {ft1         :pid(64415):tid(0x7f62e168f780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x9fa650      ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: START delete: db<0xa08d08>, transLId<2>
S> {ft1         :pid(64415):tid(0x7f62e168f780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x9fa650      ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: SQLITE_BUSY:  db<0xa08d08>
S> {ft1         :pid(64415):tid(0x7f62e168f780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x9fa650      ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: SQLITE_BUSY:  db<0xa08d08>
S> {ft3         :pid(64417):tid(0x7fbf3b3da780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x1fedff0     ):pSqlInsertReadTrans }: DONE  insert: db<0x1ffc028>, transLId<4>
S> {sv0         :pid(64418):tid(0x7f275dffc780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x2045be0     ):pSqlInsertReadTrans }: START insert: db<(nil)>
S> {ft2         :pid(64416):tid(0x7f4f3fa74780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x100a320     ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: START delete: db<0x1017858>, transLId<3>
S> {ft2         :pid(64416):tid(0x7f4f3fa74780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x100a320     ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: SQLITE_BUSY:  db<0x1017858>
S> {sv0         :pid(64418):tid(0x7f275dffc780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x2045be0     ):pSqlInsertReadTrans }: DONE  insert: db<0x204ec78>, transLId<5>
S> {ft3         :pid(64417):tid(0x7fbf3b3da780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x1fedff0     ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: START delete: db<0x1ffb2a8>, transLId<4>
S> {ft3         :pid(64417):tid(0x7fbf3b3da780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x1fedff0     ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: DONE  delete: db<0x1ffb2a8>, transLId<4>
C> {ft3         :pid(64417):tid(0x7fbf3b3da780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(1):ctx(0x1ff4a60     ):pSqlInsertReadTrans }: START insert: db<(nil)>
C> {ft3         :pid(64417):tid(0x7fbf3b3da780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(1):ctx(0x1ff4a60     ):pSqlInsertReadTrans }: DONE  insert: db<0x1ffe8c8>, transLId<6>
S> {ft1         :pid(64415):tid(0x7f62e168f780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x9fa650      ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: SQLITE_BUSY:  db<0xa08d08>
S> {ft2         :pid(64416):tid(0x7f4f3fa74780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x100a320     ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: SQLITE_BUSY:  db<0x1017858>
S> {ft1         :pid(64415):tid(0x7f62e168f780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x9fa650      ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: SQLITE_BUSY:  db<0xa08d08>
S> {ft2         :pid(64416):tid(0x7f4f3fa74780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x100a320     ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: SQLITE_BUSY:  db<0x1017858>
S> {ft1         :pid(64415):tid(0x7f62e168f780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x9fa650      ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: SQLITE_BUSY:  db<0xa08d08>
S> {ft2         :pid(64416):tid(0x7f4f3fa74780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x100a320     ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: SQLITE_BUSY:  db<0x1017858>
S> {ft1         :pid(64415):tid(0x7f62e168f780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x9fa650      ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: SQLITE_BUSY:  db<0xa08d08>
S> {ft2         :pid(64416):tid(0x7f4f3fa74780):B:dlv(0):ctxId( 0):rc(2):ctx(0x100a320     ):pSqlDeleteReadTrans }: SQLITE_BUSY:  db<0x1017858>
```

> Question: any Idea to go further ?

Comment: You never mentioned `busy_timeout`. And why are you using a database optimized for a single writer?

Comment: I don't set "busy_timeout" right now… but I "sleep" after a SQLITE_BUSY for 10000 microseconds…

Comment: adding…

    EXEC(1,"PRAGMA busy_timeout = 10        ;")

does not help.

Comment: Why 10 ms? Try 10000.

Comment: the pragma value is "ms" = milliseconds = 10^-3… but I tested this already … nothing helps…

Answer (score 0):

The **first** comment is my answer… using **sqlite** with a "#memdb#" is *no* problem… but… **no** persistance possible.

```
  # This fails with a FILE based database… "sqlite" is NOT able to share a database 
  # with multiple processes or threads
  test service-2-2-($I|$B|$C|$S) {mass "@" with TRANSACTION} \
      -setup {
        #set testdb  [file join . [file tail [MakeFile {} .dat]]]
        set testdb  "#memdb#"
        set CON1    [list {*}[FindFreeConnection $S] --storage $testdb]

        set cmd     [list {*}[getFilter Filter3.$S] --name "ft0" {*}$CON1 @]
        foreach i {1 2 3} {
          lappend cmd Filter3 --storage $testdb --name "ft$i" @
        }
        lappend cmd {*}[getServer $S] --storage $testdb --name "sv0"

        proc otFWRD {ctx} {
          $ctx Send "R" "I" [$ctx StorageCount]
        }
        set RET ""
        proc otRESU {ctx} {
          $ctx ReadT_START
          lappend ::RET [$ctx ReadC]
          $ctx ReadT_END
          lappend ::RET [$ctx ReadI]
        }
        Bg @stderr {*}$cmd
        foreach {FIRST CTX} [Create $I $CON1] break
      } \
      -body           {
        $CTX ServiceCreate FWRD otFWRD
        $CTX ServiceCreate RESU otRESU
        $CTX Send "T" RESU "FWRD:(C)" ident
        $CTX ProcessEvent -wait ONCE
        $CTX ProcessEvent -wait ONCE
        set RET
      } \
      -cleanup {
        rename $FIRST ""
      } \
      -returnCodes    ok \
      -result         "ident 1"
```